# Salesforce : Apex test class for the getting trending articles of Knowledge from Community

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I need to get trending articles from the community. I created a apex class for that by using **ConnectApi.Knowledge.getTrendingArticles(communityId, maxResult).**

I need to create a test class for that. I am using test class method provided by Salesforce for that. **setTestGetTrendingArticles(communityId, maxResults, result)** but I am getting this error "System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: No matching test result found for Knowledge.getTrendingArticles(String communityId, Integer maxResults). Before calling this, call Knowledge.setTestGetTrendingArticles(String communityId, Integer maxResults, ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersionCollection result) to set the expected test result."

public without sharing class ConnectTopicCatalogController {

```
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion> getAllTrendingArticles(){
    string commId = [Select Id from Network where Name = 'Customer Community v5'].Id;
    ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersionCollection mtCollection = ConnectApi.Knowledge.getTrendingArticles(commId, 12);
    System.debug('getAllTrendingTopics '+JSON.serializePretty(mtCollection.items));
    List<ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion> topicList = new List<ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion>();
    for(ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion mtopic : mtCollection.items)
    {
            topicList.add(mtopic);
    }
   return topicList;
}
```

}

Test class that I am using for this

```
public class ConnectTopicCatalogControllerTest {

public static final string communityId = [Select Id from Network where Name = 'Customer Community v5'].Id;

@isTest
static void getTrendingArticles(){
    ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersionCollection knowledgeResult = new ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersionCollection();

    List<ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion> know = new List<ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion>();
    know.add(new ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion());
    know.add(new ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion());
    system.debug('know '+know);
    knowledgeResult.items = know;
    
    // Set the test data
    ConnectApi.Knowledge.setTestGetTrendingArticles(null, 12, knowledgeResult);
    List<ConnectApi.KnowledgeArticleVersion> res = ConnectTopicCatalogController.getAllTrendingArticles();
    
    // The method returns the test page, which we know has two items in it.
    Test.startTest();
    System.assertEquals(12, res.size());
    Test.stopTest();
   
}
```

}

I need help to solve the test class
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller expects the articles to be inside the 'Customer Community v5' community, but you are passing the communityId parameter as null to the setTestGetTrendingArticles method.